# Add content between header and footer in page Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2, addition, block

```
$listBusBlock = $listOfBuses->getLayout()->createBlock('Imonn\Bookings\Block\Buslist')->setTemplate('Imonn_Bookings::Busbooking/listOfBusses.phtml')->toHtml();
$this->getResponse()->setBody($listBusBlock);
```

in the above PHP code, I want to add $listBusBlock between header and footer

if I use `$this->getResponse()->setBody($listBusBlock);` the content is set to all body and header and footer is gone. what should is use instead of setBody so that the content can be added between header and footer

Any help is appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to show your custom block in your custom phtml file?

Comment: yes. I want to show $listBusBlock in custom phtml file

Comment: Do you want to add contents for all pages or a different page?

Comment: only to one page. I tried this "$this->_resultPageFactory->create()->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($listBusBlock);" but it throws an error "Call to a member function append() on boolean" now getLayout() is working but there is a problem is append()

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in your phtml, if you want to show CMS Static Block in any template in Magento 2.

```
echo $block->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Imonn\Bookings\Block\Buslist')
          ->setTemplate('Imonn_Bookings::Busbooking/listOfBusses.phtml')
          ->toHtml();
```

Hope this will solve your issue.
Or you can add a static block to your cms page from admin side.

Comment: I want to redirect to phtml file from controller

Comment: So the issue is showing block or redirecting? didn't get you.

Comment: From A phtml file, I came to controller through from submission. now I want to go to B phtml file from the controller.  the block is <block class="Imonn\Bookings\Block\Buslist" name="buslist" template="listOfBusses.phtml" /> i want to go to listOfBusses.phtml from the controller